# There is no bettercap file in the file system

Tags: security, networking, kali-linux

I downloaded bettercap by using this command `sudo apt install bettercap` but when I go to this location `/usr/share/` I don't find any folder named bettercap and there's no caplets folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the caplets that are installed by running bettercap and then using the command 'caplets.show'. I don't think they are installed by default so if you don't have them or need to update them then that can be done using the command 'caplets.update'.

I've included a link below to the docs that should help with this issue as well as others you may run into when using bettercap.

https://www.bettercap.org/modules/core/caplets/